# Calling c++ assemblies with C#

Tags: c#, c

I have a c++ dll which I need to use in my .NET code.

How do I call methods on this library, and use the result in my code?

e.g. C++ library has a method called Move(int) which returns a 1 for true and a 0 for false.

I didn't write the C++ library, it is used to control the movement of a robotic machine.

Comment: C or C++? Title says latter, everything else says former.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx). So for example if your unmanaged library exports a function which takes an integer value as argument and returns another integer you could define a managed wrapper for this method in C# decorating it with the [`[DllImport]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DllImport("foo.dll")]
public static extern int Move(int arg);
```

and then use this method directly in managed code:

```
int result = Move(123);
```

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173184.aspx

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
public class MyClass
{
    #region PInvokes
    [DllImport("Your.dll")]
    static public extern int Move(int val);
....
```

If, once, you would have to Interop C++ classes, here is a good article about it.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/marshalCPPclass.aspx